# JMeter Test never ends from Non- GUI Mode

Tags: jmeter

When I run the following test form the NON- GUI  Mode, test never ends, not sure what  went wrong.
Where as when I run the same test from  GUI Mode test completes with in ~3 min's
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test will end as soon as JMeter will receive the responses for all your 202 samples.

By default JMeter will wait for the response **forever** (or as long as the underlying operating system and/or [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) allows), if that's too long for you - the relevant timeouts can be set under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-http-request#Best%20Practices))

[image]